# Regex searching for first occurrence of word

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

In CSV file I have couple thousands strings similar to that 20024la - (character number may vary but there is always white space before and after dash).

I need to remove all those strings including white spaces but leave everything that is after that.

Example string:

> 20023la - 100 lt storage cylinder RBA100 - 1120820

"20023la - " has to be removed from that example

Comment: Can the `20023la - ` or `20024la - ` occur at any place in the string or will it always be at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this as well:

```
^(\b\d+[^\s-]+\s+-\s+)
```

It will match the first occurance, removing `^` will match `ALL`.

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/3l16bqR6Xp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pattern like:

```
\w+\s-\s(.*)
```

**replace string**:

```
$1
```

**result:**

```
100 lt storage cylinder RBA100 - 1120820
```

**example**:

> http://regex101.com/r/lD5zE3

Comment: Almost but I need everything that is after first dash, so the result should be 100 lt storage cylinder RBA100 - 1120820

Comment: I've tried that before, the problem is that it is looking for are occurrences of dash with white spaces while it should stop at first one (because one line of text contains more than one dash with spaces) http://regex101.com/r/iE4fI8